# PHP object losing its data when casting to array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, object

I work on the PHP framework Laravel 5, and here's my question :
I get from my DB an object with several values.
When I echo this, it show all the correct data, however, as soon as I cast it into an array, it  becomes an empty array, why ?

```
$TonnageTotal = Collecte\Produit::pluck('tonnage'); //put everything I need into $TonnageTotal
$arrTonnage = get_object_vars($TonnageTotal); //then cast it
```

It does the same if I do this :

```
$arrTonnage=(array)$TonnageTotal;
```

Values I want to get are integer and are meant to be array_sum();

What am I missing ?

Comment: get_object_vars only gets you _“accessible non-static properties”_ - you sure that is the case for all the properties in question?

Comment: Laravel model properties aren't simply properties, they're using magic internally to make them accessible, so they won't cast directly to array properties.... that's why Laravel provides `toArray()` and other similar methods

Comment: You're right, thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may convert from collection to array by using `toArray()` method.

```
$arrTonnage = $TonnageTotal->toArray();
```